# Is it possible to play this stream using HTML5/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, jplayer, shoutcast

Basically trying to play some live audio streams in an app I'm porting to the browser.

Stream example: http://kzzp-fm.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/877/19757/v1/auth.akacast.akamaistream.net/kzzp-fm/

I have tried HTML5 audio tag and jPlayer with no luck.  I know next to nothing about streaming audio, however, when I examine the HTTP response header the specified content type is "audio/aacp" (not sure if that helps).

I'm hoping someone with more knowledge of audio formats could point me in the right direction here.

Comment: Your link is broken. Also can you give us details on what you have tried that didn't work?

Comment: Yes I just noticed that none of the URLs passed back from the API are working all of a sudden

Comment: When the above link WAS working, HTML5 audio tag didn't seem to work though it worked fine with a url to an m4a file.  Same with jPlayer.  Only with jPlayer I had no idea what to specified as the supplied format for the live audio stream so I tried once each time with each supported format with no luck.

Comment: You said you were using an m4a file. I'm not very experienced with the audio tag either, but as far as I know: it only supports Ogg, MP3, and WAV. The support for those varies by browser too (scroll down to "example") http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't with AAC+ being *playable*, the issue is with decoding the **streaming** ACC wrapper called ADTS. The [Audio Data Transport Stream [pdf]](http://www.iis.fraunhofer.de/content/dam/iis/en/documents_ALT/AAC_Transport_FormatsR1.0-1tcm183-102284.pdf) or "MP4-contained AAC streamed over HTTP using the SHOUTcast protocol" can be decoded and therefore played by only a couple media players (e.g., foobar2000, Winamp, and VLC).

[I had the same issue while trying to work with the SHOUTcast API to get HTML5 Audio playback for all the listed stations](https://getsatisfaction.com/schillmania/topics/sm2_unable_to_play_shoutcast_stations). Unfortunately it doesn't look like there's anything that can be done from our perspective, only the browser vendors can decide to add support for ADTS decoding. **It is a [documented issue in Chrome/WebKit](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40344)**. There are 60+ people (including myself) following the issue, which is marked as "WontFix".

Comment: Got an example of a stream with AAC+ that uses a container other than ADTS?  I haven't seen one.

Comment: There are all sorts of containers for AAC+ Unlike most other containers, ADTS headers are present before each AAC raw_data_block or block of 2 to 4 raw_data_blocks. This allows a client to "jump in" at any point because the required information (about the incoming audio data) is always sent in between the audio packets. Most MPEG4 containers keep all of the header information either all at the beginning or end of the file. But when you're broadcasting like a radio station there is no "beginning" or "end" of the file/broadcast. The audio data has an unknowable Content-Length.

Comment: Right, I understand that, but I am asking if you have seen a live stream out there that isn't using ADTS.  I've looked and have not seen one.

Comment: I don't believe there is any other ACC container that would allow for "streaming." ADTS is the only one as far as I know that sends the headers before each AAC data block. Every other container seems to be designed for finite-length media (where you know the beginning and end). Streaming audio like a radio broadcast doesn't fit into that structure.

Comment: Any known workarounds?  Possible with something like jPlayer?

Comment: Good news!  It looks like it's been fixed since Chrome 37.  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=275681  Has anyone ran a compatibility test with other browsers recently?  Maybe I'll put one together this weekend.  aacPlus served from the AudioPump CDN playing in the current stable version of Chrome:  http://project.wnyc.org/test/issues/streamtest/#http://cdn.audiopump.co/radioreddit/main_heaac_64k