# switching SHOUTcast audio streams HTML5 audio player and JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, audio, shoutcast

Hello i'll paste evrything below but what's happening is it's updating the page with the correct url but only the "hi" stream plays (which is loaded with the browser) if i pres "lo" it stops the audio but doesn't play and clicking "hi" then starts the hi stream again and plays as normal, it is obvious when this is done too as when lo stream is pressed playtime slider is at the beginning and displays 0; when it's working with hi it's at the end and counting up:

so $(document).ready functions are:

```
                var audio = $('#audioPlayer');
            $('#hi').on("click", function () {
                audio.attr("src", "http://96.31.83.94:8061/;");
                /****************/
                audio[0].pause();
                audio[0].load();//suspends and restores all audio element
                audio[0].play();
                /****************/
                });

            $('#lo').on("click", function () {
                audio.attr("src", "http://85.17.167.136:8534/;");
                /****************/
                audio[0].pause();
                audio[0].load();//suspends and restores all audio element
                audio[0].play();
                /****************/
                });
```

Player and Buttons:

```
        <div id="audioPanel" class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <audio id="audioPlayer" class="audioPlayer" src="http://96.31.83.94:8061/;" controls autoplay>
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio><br>
            <div id="streamButtons" class="btn-group">
                <button id="lo" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Lo</button>
                <button id="hi" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Hi</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

view source doesn't change if i F5 after the button is pushed but in firebug and inspect element it does change to the correct "lo" url yet for some reason won't play... please help.

This is obviously not the only thing in doc.ready but it's 1st in the list.

EDIT: here is the player after the lo button has been initiated

```
   <div id="audioPanel" class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<audio id="audioPlayer" class="audioPlayer" autoplay="" controls="" src="http://85.17.167.136:8534/;"> Your browser does not support the audio element. </audio>
<br>
    <div id="streamButtons" class="btn-group">
<button id="lo" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Lo</button>
<button id="hi" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Hi</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine except that the shoutcast for the one with the source with 85.17.167.136:8534 won't work as its content type is audio/aacp which has ADTS wrapper around it, as Brad mentioned below, is not supported in HTML5 player. So i'd suggest you to search for audio/mpeg content or you will need a flash player to play that stream.

For more information check this out: [Is it possible to play this stream using HTML5/javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273161/is-it-possible-to-play-this-stream-using-html5-javascript)

Comment: that's it... not the code but the aac problem. thankyou for spotting that. it will never play not on any device with an html5 player so my solution will have to be to load it someother way or extend the number of the higher streams available. cheers

Comment: Specifically, it's not that AAC isn't supported, its the ADTS wrapper around it.  Many browsers can play AAC just fine, but it would have to be in an MP4/M4A container which is difficult to stream.  In my opinion, this is a significant oversight by the browser developers, and you can see their arguments over this issue in the development mailing lists.